# How is Extreme Weight Loss filmed?

Tags: extreme-weight-loss

Each episode of Extreme Weight Loss cover about a year.  There are currently four episodes released for the current season.  For this show to not take forever to release they must be overlapping the filming of the episodes somehow.  How are they filming this show?

Comment: What is there to understand?  They spend a few weeks shooting.  Then they wait three months (or whatever) and then do some more.

Answer (score 6):

> How are they filming this show?

According to executive producer JD Roth in an [interview with Michael Schneider - 2016](https://www.tvinsider.com/2892/qa-extreme-weight-loss-producer-on-nba-episodes-potential-spinoff-series-and-schedule/), about the schedule and shootings, they shoot 2 seasons at the same time.

> **How does this work? How do you manage to work on multiple episodes at once for an entire year?**
>
> > It’s a unique production model. There aren’t many shows that can figure out a way to afford a calendar year to shoot an episode. Most unscripted shows in primetime happen over a very short period of time. That’s the beauty of these shows. But when we started shooting 365 days, it changed the model. We had to come up with a scenario that would provide us with a way to follow these people for a full year but not have to shoot every single day. Think about it, we’re asking the network for casting 16 months before the episode will air. So we start in January casting for the following summer. By the time we cast the people, bring them for final casting, prepare them and then narrow down the people that we want, we’re still about 14 months before the first episode airing. So it’s tricky because you’re doing two seasons at once, all the time, and we’ve been doing that for the last six years.

Then, about the way to follow up: candidates have a schedule, and they're being monitored. Anytime the producers notice that something is going wrong, they set a meeting (and shoot it). When the schedule is ok, and the candidate work-out has good results, shootings are just a follow-up. Otherwise, they have "unplanned" meetings with host Chris Powell.

> **Has it gotten easier at all, now that you know the tricks of how to do this?**
>
> > The format has evolved, and the proprietary way to get the weight off the contestants has also evolved. And the way we shoot the show has evolved. **So we’ve gotten smarter about knowing when the real great emotional tent-pole moments are**. We will find now that we can tell. Have they gone radio silent? Did they not show up for one of their workouts? When these hidden messages come our way, as producers we know that’s a signal. If we see that weight loss has gone from 7 or 8 pounds a week to 1 or 2 pounds a week, we know something’s up. **So sometimes we will fly Chris Powell out there and have him do surveillance for a couple of days outside of their house, outside of their gym, and in the shadows he can see what’s going on, then diagnose the problem and confront them about it.**

Answer (score 1):

A show like that is filmed a number of years before it's released. For them to show four episodes covering a year, they simply would've filmed at four points throughout the year, and edited together a number of shows when all the footage was available. A year later, you see it on TV.

Comment: And while that's true, can you provide any evidence that this is what this particular show did?